# Issue with ConstraintLayout and weighted chain

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm building a simple portrait layout with 6 chained elements:

- 2 x Spaces
- 4 x Views (actually they're a more complex views but issue is   reproducible with empty view too)

My goal is:
 - spaces must take 10% of parent's height (5% each)
 - views must take 90% of parent's height (22,5% each)

For to reach this, I'm using `layout_constraintVertical_weight`.

Issue is that when **weight_sum = 10**, all views disappears, instead when sum is different from 10 (for example 9,9) it's works properly. I've already used weighted views (with LinearLayout) but I never found this issue...

Versions:

`Android Studio 3.1.2`

`implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'`

Any idea?! 
Thanks :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout   
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Space
    android:id="@+id/space"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="0.5" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/space"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="2.25" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view1"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="2.25" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/green"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="2.25" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/red"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/space2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view3"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="2.25" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/space2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view4"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="0.5" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>`
```

[Screen with sum 9,9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cKgu.png)

[Screen with sum 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mbx9l.png)

Difference is just `layout_constraintVertical_weight` of **space2**

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/space2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view4"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="0.49" />
```

Comment: Do you need a solution or you just wanna discuss this issue?

Comment: A quick an dirty solution is to set sum to 9 (for example) and recalculate all percentages.. But why I can't set 10?! Is a bug?

Comment: Looks like a bug. But using a weight isn't good solution anyway because it is very heavy for android OS. I recommend to use Guideline to place  items as a percentage. So in you case you could use two horizontal Guidelines with 5 and 95 offset. It will be much better for performance.

Comment: Either a weird bug, a poorly documented feature or both. I would report it to the Google team.